# Which is the most reactive element in the periodic table?

Tags: periodic-trends, reactivity

Which is the most reactive element in the periodic table? Is it francium, caesium, lithium or fluorine?

Comment: What about radioactive elements?

Answer (score 0):

Fluorine is the most reactive non radioactive element on periodic table.

It exists in gaseous form at room temperature and even reacts with glass. So it is almost impossible to store it in pure form.and caesium is the most reactive metal

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! Take the [tour] to get familiar with this site. Mathematical expressions and equations can be [formatted](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/86/4945) using $\LaTeX$ syntax. For more information in general have a look at the [help]. At the moment this reads more like a comment than an actual answer - could you elaborate a little more. With a bit more rep, [you will be able to post comments](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment) on any question/answer.